# POST xml data using java

Tags: java, xml, post

I have used the following java code to POST xml data to a remote url and get the response. Here, I am using an xml file as the input. What I need is to pass the xml as a string not a file... is there anyway I can do this? Can someone help me? Thanks a lot!

**Java code**

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.InputStreamRequestEntity;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.PostMethod;

public class xmlToString {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String strURL = "https://simulator.expediaquickconnect.com/connect/ar";
    String strXMLFilename = "xmlfile.xml";
    File input = new File(strXMLFilename);
    PostMethod post = new PostMethod(strURL);
    try {
        post.setRequestEntity(new InputStreamRequestEntity(
                new FileInputStream(input), input.length()));
        post.setRequestHeader("Content-type",
                "text/xml; charset=ISO-8859-1");
        HttpClient httpclient = new HttpClient();

        int result = httpclient.executeMethod(post);
        System.out.println("Response status code: " + result);
        System.out.println("Response body: ");
        System.out.println(post.getResponseBodyAsString());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        post.releaseConnection();
    }
}

   }
```

**UPDATE**: I need to pass XML as a string and remove involving xml file...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The setRequestEntity method on org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.PostMethod has an overloaded version that accepts [StringRequestEntity](http://www.docjar.com/docs/api/org/apache/commons/httpclient/methods/StringRequestEntity.html) as argument. You should use this if you wish to pass in your data as a string (as opposed to an input stream). So your code would look something like this:

```
String xml = "whatever.your.xml.is.here";
PostMethod post = new PostMethod(strURL);     
try {
    StringRequestEntity requestEntity = new StringRequestEntity(xml);
    post.setRequestEntity(requestEntity);
....
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: this dint work for me. please help this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32884587/how-to-sent-xml-file-endpoint-url-in-restful-web-service/32884767#32884767

Comment: How can I elegantly create XML key value pairs instead of using pure Strings?

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the XML to String from this method

```
public String convertXMLFileToString(String fileName) 
{ 
   try{ 
       DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance(); 
       InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(fileName)); 
       org.w3c.dom.Document doc = documentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder().parse(inputStream); 
       StringWriter stw = new StringWriter(); 
       Transformer serializer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer(); 
       serializer.transform(new DOMSource(doc), new StreamResult(stw)); 
       return stw.toString(); 
   } 
   catch (Exception e) { 
       e.printStackTrace(); 
   } 
   return null; 
}
```

Add you can pass this string as a parameter on `PostMethod` like this.

```
PostMethod post = new PostMethod(strURL);
post.addParamter("paramName", convertXMLFileToString(strXMLFilename ) );
```

The whole XML will be transmitted to the client in a `queryString`.

Comment: Hi, Thanks a lot for your answer, I don't need to involve a xml file at all instead I need to pass xml as a string... is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

To get your XML file contents as a String use (add catch-block for IOException)

```
StringBuilder bld = new StringBuilder();
FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(input);
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
for (String line = reader.readLine(); line != null; line = reader.readLine()) {
    bld.append(line);
}
String xml = bld.toString();
```

The better way is to use Java Web Services JAX-WS or Java Restful Web Services JAX-RS.

Comment: Hi, Thanks a lot for your answer, I don't need to involve a xml file at all instead I need to pass xml as a string... is there a way to do that?