# HTTP post XML data in C#

Tags: c#, xml, http-headers

I need to HTTP post XML data to a URL that has Textarea with the name of XMLdata. My XMl data is ready and is inside of    XDocument Sendingxml = xml; but the post code that I have tried is not working. Mostly because I don't know how to put the XML data in postData Variable as it  only accept string. This is my code:

```
        XDocument Sendingxml = xml;

        //  string Sendingxml = "<?xml version=1.0 encoding=UTF-8> <PluginData> <Credential UserName=avosfieldagent01 AuthenticationToken=61cc3957744742dca238c4dd7cbca702 /><Session><PropertyAddress>5 Crosskey</PropertyAddress><PropertyAddress2/><PropertyCity>California</PropertyCity><PropertyState>CA</PropertyState><PropertyZip>92620</PropertyZip><PropertyType>Condo</PropertyType><SourceReferenceId>45643</SourceReferenceId><SessionId>2013070100158346</SessionId><SessionCompleteReturnURL/><CustomerId/><BluebookOrderCheckSum>681a598cf23f412095f6092c281823e6</BluebookOrderCheckSum><BluebookOrderId>11160</BluebookOrderId> </Session></PluginData>";

        // Create a request using a URL that can receive a post. 
        WebRequest request =
            WebRequest.Create("https://test.bluebookcva.net/order/testdirectplugin/3");
        // Set the Method property of the request to POST.
        request.Method = "POST";

        // Create POST data and convert it to a byte array.
        string postData = "XMLData=" + Sendingxml;    //My problem is here as I need postData  as XDocument.


        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
        // Set the ContentType property of the WebRequest.
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        // Set the ContentLength property of the WebRequest.
        request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
        // Get the request stream.
        Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
        // Write the data to the request stream.
        dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        // Close the Stream object.
        dataStream.Close();
        // Get the response.
        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
        // Display the status.
        Console.WriteLine(((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription);
        // Get the stream containing content returned by the server.
        dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        // Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
        // Read the content.
        string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
        // Display the content.
        Console.WriteLine(responseFromServer);
        // Clean up the streams.
        reader.Close();
        dataStream.Close();
        response.Close();
```

Answer (score 115, accepted):

**In General:**

An example of an easy way to post XML data and get the response (as a string) would be the following function:

```
public string postXMLData(string destinationUrl, string requestXml)
{
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(destinationUrl);
    byte[] bytes;
    bytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(requestXml);
    request.ContentType = "text/xml; encoding='utf-8'";
    request.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
    request.Method = "POST";
    Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
    requestStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    requestStream.Close();
    HttpWebResponse response;
    response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
        Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        string responseStr = new StreamReader(responseStream).ReadToEnd();
        return responseStr;
    }
    return null;
}
```

**In your specific situation:**

Instead of:

```
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
```

use:

```
request.ContentType = "text/xml; encoding='utf-8'";
```

Also, remove:

```
string postData = "XMLData=" + Sendingxml;
```

And replace:

```
byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
```

with:

```
byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Sendingxml.ToString());
```

Comment: Thanks, but what about this 2 lines,    string postData = "XMLData=" + Sendingxml;
            byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData); I nned to have postData  as XDocument, because I need to send XMLData as xml format not string.

Comment: Sorry about that. I've updated my answer with a more complete solution.

Comment: Thanks, I have replaced with all you said here, but still it does not even redirect to the URL.

Comment: Are you sure the problem is with how the data is being POSTed and not the data itself or something else? For reference, here's a code snippet I personally use to POST XML data to the Youtube XML API, and which I know to work: http://pastebin.com/EGmeB05J

Comment: please tel me which lib user for this code? Are there have maven dependency?

Comment: @ThilinaSampath This is C# code. Are you looking for [How to POST XML data in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6580193/post-xml-data-using-java)?

Comment: Content-Type : application/xml

Comment: What if I was on the other side? What if I was the receiver for such request, how can I read the posted data or XML?

Comment: To receive it in mvc Controller , do something like this

[HttpPost]
[ValidateInput(false)]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    string xml = "";
    if(Request.InputStream != null){
        StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(Request.InputStream);
        string x = stream.ReadToEnd();
        xml = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(x);
    }
    ...
    return View(model);
}

Comment: Add these two lines if you need to send it ssl: 
ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
                        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

Answer (score 8):

AlliterativeAlice's example helped me tremendously. In my case, though, the server I was talking to didn't like having single quotes around `utf-8` in the content type. It failed with a generic `"Server Error"` and it took hours to figure out what it didn't like:

```
request.ContentType = "text/xml; encoding=utf-8";
```

Comment: Thank you! I was having the same problem. Removed the ticks and all good.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time and making sure you warn us!