# Send XML to RESTful web service from Unity

Tags: c#, xml, rest, unity-container

I'm using WWW to interact with a RESTful web service. I have a problem sending XML files to the server through POST requests, though. This is my code:

```
if(Syste.IO.File.Exists(filePath)){
    byte [] raw = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);              
    WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
    form.AddBinaryData("fileUpload", raw, "", "text/xml");
    WWW www = new WWW(host + auth + "/behaviors", form);
    StartCoroutine(myCoroutine(www));
}

IEnumerator myCoroutine(WWW www){
    yield return www;

    if (www.error == null)
    {
        Debug.Log("Text: " + www.text);
        proceedToNextRequest = true;
    } else {
        Debug.Log("Error: "+ www.error);
        Application.Quit();
    }    
}
```

The answer from the server is, though, "Unsupported Media Type", and I've no idea what's wrong. I generally use POSTMAN on Google Chrome to send these requests, and it works fine. Any tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution for this: instead of using the WWW class(which, anyway, according to the [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/WWW.html) I'm pretty sure it can be used for this pupose), I'm using [WebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest(v=vs.110).aspx). How this can be achieved is very well explained in the previous link and in this question: [HTTP post XML data in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17535872/http-post-xml-data-in-c-sharp)