# C# WebClient 404 Error Large String

Tags: c#, xml

This is wrecking my brain for a while now. The code works fine when I post a smaller XML string. As soon as I add more XML nodes and post, I get the infamous '404 Error'

I'm posting XML data as a string to a Generic Handler in C#.

```
string strXML = "Large XML Content Here";

WebClient client = new WebClient();

string xmlResult = "";

try
{
    xmlResult = client.DownloadString(_workContext.AccountingWebServiceLink 
                                    + "?action=updateprimary&xml=" 
                                    + System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(strXML));
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    System.IO.File.AppendAllText(Server.MapPath("~/addressXMLReturnError.txt"),
                         "Error: " + e.Message + " returnValue = " + xmlResult);
}
```

I think it might have something to do with the server not accepting large strings?

Comment: It might be the limit so try the `<httpRuntime maxUrlLength="xxx" />` tin your web.config app, but I think the error is different in such case.

Comment: @PawełŁukasik I will give that a try now and see if it makes a difference.  FYI: The string length I'm posting is 1562 long

Comment: If you have access to the code of the server you are sending the XML to, I would advise you to do an HTML POST, and put the XML in the body after encoding it as BASE64. 

https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/a-beginners-guide-to-http-and-rest--net-16340

Comment: @PawełŁukasik I set the 'maxUrlLength="6144"' and still got the same error.

Comment: then it's not the limit but some special characters in the data. convert to BASE64 as @BertusvanZyl suggested

Comment: @PawełŁukasik will try converting to Base64. I can confirm there are no special chars in the string.

Comment: @Orion XML has a lot of special characters like <, & that has special meaning for URLs

Comment: @PawełŁukasik I'm using System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode so it formats the special chars.  Then I decode it on the server. it works fine when the xml data is smaller. So this has to be a string size issue.

Comment: Please see my comment above about using a POST, and putting data in body. Putting all the data in the address is like creating a textfile, and then putting all the text in the name of the file, in stead of inside the file.

Comment: @BertusvanZyl I will give it a try now and let you know how it goes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it working using suggestions from comments above.

So posting the XML data is the best route for me.

Using code from this SO post > [HTTP post XML data in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17535872/http-post-xml-data-in-c-sharp)

To receive the data on the other side, check out this link > https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Enviar-datos-por-el-metodo-2e580ace