# How to pass Data set to web API using HTTP POST

Tags: c#, dataset, http-post, asp.net-web-api2, parameter-passing

I need to pass `dataset` to web API to store `dataset` in database. this is my c# client side code. Previously I pass person data like this (**commented line**). But in this time I have a `Dataset`. How can I pass `dataset` to web api using http POST?

```
DataSet rslt;
```

In this `dataset` , there have four columns as `pid,proid,name,msg`

```
private void btnInsert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        try
        {
            //person p = new person { PID = 1, ProjectID = 5, Name= "paul",  Msg = "hello"};
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:10927/");
            var response = client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/Person", p).Result;
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                Console.Write("Success");
            }
            else
                Console.Write("Error");
        }
        catch (Exception x)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(x.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

In my web API this part of my controller class:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody]Person value)
{
    long id;
    PersonPersistence dp = new PersonPersistence();
    id = dp.addPerson(value);
    HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created);
    response.Headers.Location = new Uri(Request.RequestUri, string.Format("Manager/{0}", id));
    return response;
}
```

and this is part of my `PersonPersistence.class`

```
public long addPerson(Person t)
{
    long id = 0;
    try
    {
        string sqlString = "INSERT INTO tblperson(pid,proid,name,dis) VALUES (@1,@2,@3,@4);";
        MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand cmd = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand(sqlString, conn);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@1", t.Time);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@2", t.Date);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@3", t.Batch);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@4", t.Leture);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        id = cmd.LastInsertedId;
        return id;
    }
    catch (MySqlException x)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(x.Number);
    }
    return id;
}
```

Comment: Using a DataSet for that sucks, but if you do need to do that I'd serialize/deserialize it to XML

Comment: @hardkoded I new to this field sir, I haven't good idea about this.please help me to solve

Comment: If you want to use `DataSet` (whatever the reason is), I think that the most perfect way would be, if you send XML and you can easily serialize your `DataSet` to XML with `DataSet`'s `GetXml()` method, and then in server side, deserialize it back, using `DataSet`'s  `ReadXml(XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xml)))`.

Comment: @SeM Can you give me a sample code sir,i"m not clear this

Answer (score 0):

You can convert datatable to an xml string using following

```
           DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            dt.WriteXml(ms);
            long length = ms.Length;
            ms.Position = 0;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[length];
            ms.Read(buffer,0,(int)length);
            string xml = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer);
```

Comment: See following posting which sends the byte[] : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17535872/http-post-xml-data-in-c-sharp