# CURL --data-binary to C# HttpWebrequest

Tags: c#, rest, curl, post, httpwebrequest

I have below curl request that I want to convert to C# code. I'm just not sure what is the equivalent of "**--data-binary**" in HttpWebRequest.

`curl -s -H "Content-Type:application/xml" -X POST --data-binary @C:\path\to\file.xml "https://somerestURL?create"`

So far, below is my code:

```
var xmlFile = "C:\\path\\to\\file.xml";
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
NetworkCredential cred = new NetworkCredential(uname, cipher);
CredentialCache cache = new CredentialCache { { url, "Basic", cred } };
request.PreAuthenticate = true;
request.Credentials = cache;
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "application/xml";
```

I can provide information if you need more. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I focused on searching conversion/equivalent of curl to c# code but it got me no luck.
So, I researched about XML POSTING and below is my working code.

```
        // initiate xml 
        XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
        xml.Load(xmlFile);
        byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(xml.InnerXml);

        // setup request
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        NetworkCredential cred = new NetworkCredential(uname, cipher);
        CredentialCache cache = new CredentialCache { { url, "Basic", cred } };
        request.PreAuthenticate = true;
        request.Credentials = cache;
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "application/xml; encoding='utf-8'";
        request.ContentLength = bytes.Length;

        // stream
        Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
        requestStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        requestStream.Close();

        // response        
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.Default);
        var xmlResponse = readStream.ReadToEnd();
```

I got my idea from this post and changed a bit based on my requirement:
[HTTP post XML data in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17535872/http-post-xml-data-in-c-sharp)